# How to set environment variables for MSVS 2019 with old version of MSVS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, environment-variables

I've installed MSVC++ 6.0 in my computer so it has set the environment variables.

Now I've installed MSVC++ 2019 but when I go to

> Computer  properties->advanced system settings->Environment variables

Include contains only `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\atl\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\mfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include`

and the remaining path, libs... all contains folders of MSVC++6 but not 2019.

I need this because sometimes I want to compile my C++20 code from CMD not from IDE.

I've run as administrator `VsDevCmd.bat` but it didn't make changes!

So how can I set the environment variables for visual Studio 2019?

Comment: nobody dares to drop at least a comment?!

Comment: How the VS6 installer abuses the system environment is not relevant.  You are running the wrong .bat file to setup for C/C++ building.  There are multiple vc*.bat files, favor the Start menu shortcuts.

Comment: @HansPassant: In fact I've installed VS6 first then VS19. VS6 sets the environment variables (INCLUDE, LIB, PATH...) but VS19 doesn't. If I run from a cmd: `cl mysource.cpp` I get errors like `file "initialized_list" not found`. This is because it uses `cl.exe` of VS6 not 2019. Please help. I don't have a clue about setting up them. If possible to replace the old variables with VS2019 It'll be OK for me. Thank you.